# Issue with executing an Android application over 2GB of APK file?

Tags: android, apk, galaxy, dex

I am trying to execute an APK file size over 2GB and it's giving me an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class: MyApplication... on path: DexPathList[..]
```

It successfully installs the APK on the device but when I try to execute the application, I get the above error.

I have tested installing and executing an APK with size of 1.99GB but it worked fine. Then also I've tested with APK size 2.01GB but it failed with above error.

The device I'm using to test is Galaxy S8 with Android Nougat.

This APK file isn't intended to be uploaded on Google Play Store which means it isn't going to use the expansion files; all of the contents will be included inside of the APK file itself.

I have tried many methods to fix the error by researching them but I had no luck. Things I've tried:

1. Cleaned and rebuilt.
2. Enabled & disabled multidex in build.gradle.
3. Give full path of the MainActivity & MyApplication class in AndroidManifest.
4. Tested with many other gradle versions.
5. Disabled proguard.
6. etc.

Basically I think I tried almost all of the suggestions online about ClassNotFoundException with dex.

I thought since it works with anything under 2GB, I can only guess that there is a size limit of an APK that a device can run?

Or is there any other solution that I can try?

Comment: That may be a filesystem-level issue. 2GB is what we refer to as "damn big".

Comment: you won't be able to upload such a APK to the google play. It is not *tested* to run such large APK files. It is still not proxibited, but  here you are *on your own*

Comment: Do you see any other warnings/errors in logcat during installation (or during application load)? Make sure you're looking on all the logs, and not only those that produced by your application.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Please read the question carefully. The OP doesn't want to upload it to Play store.

Comment: @JWL Have you found any solution for this...? I am going to handle the same app which is more than 2gb in size..

Comment: @SuhasPatil I haven't been able to figure this one out yet. Let me know if you find something out while at it.

Comment: @AlexLipov I don't see any other weird errors except the dex one sir.

Comment: Sure, does the app with size 1.99 GB runs properly on device..?

Comment: @SuhasPatil Yes it does. No issues with it.

Comment: Okay Thanks, till then I will manage the size accordingly if possible...

Comment: @AlexLipov, I know that. If I wanted to answer the question, I'd post an answer, not a comment. I just told that it is not common practice to do this way, and there are not much people who do it this way, so not many people are able to help here.

Comment: Same issue happened when I build a unity game, when the apk size exceed 2gb